# Problema Numero Random (Scanner)

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Hola el programa así como lo ven me corre perfectamente, pero no creo que deba usar 2 objetos de la clase Scanner, eh intentando con un solo objeto y no se puede, ¿cómo podría ahorrar un objeto?

Creo que el error es porque 1ero le asigno un int y luego un String.

> Programa como juego que elige un numero random y la persona debe
>   encontrarlo, si falla le pregunta si quiere continuar o no, ayudándolo
>   a ganar

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Random {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

    int numeroElegido=0;
    int numero=0;
    String respuesta="s";
    numero=(int) (Math.random()*5+1);
    System.out.println("El numero es ->"+numero); //Es para confirmar

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
    System.out.println("Escribe un numero, ¿darás con el correcto?");
    numeroElegido =sc.nextInt();
    if(numeroElegido==numero)
    {
        System.out.println("Ganaste, el numero era->"+numeroElegido);
    }
    else if(numeroElegido>numero)
    {    System.out.println("Tu numero es mayor");}
    else if(numeroElegido<numero)
    {    System.out.println("Tu numero es menor");}

    System.out.print("Quieres volver a intentar? (s|n)->");
    respuesta=sc2.nextLine();

    }
    while(respuesta.equals("s"));
```

}
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

!Buenas!

Si, puedes realizarlo con un solo `Scanner`.

El problema que tienes es, que después de guardar un numero (ya sea **int**, **double**...) y después quieras introducir un tipo **String**, el *intro* que introduces se guarda en el *buffer* de `Scanner` y ahí empieza el problema. Para solucionarlo debes de limpiar ese *buffer*.

Te dejo el código corregido, y un comentario donde he hecho esa limpieza de *buffer*:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int numeroElegido=0;
        int numero=0;
        String respuesta="s";
        numero=(int) (Math.random()*5+1);
        System.out.println("El numero es ->"+numero); //Es para confirmar

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{

        System.out.println("Escribe un numero, ¿darás con el correcto?");
        numeroElegido =sc.nextInt();

        if(numeroElegido==numero)
        {
            System.out.println("Ganaste, el numero era->"+numeroElegido);
        }

        else if(numeroElegido>numero)

        {   
            System.out.println("Tu numero es mayor");

        }
        else if(numeroElegido<numero)

        {    
            System.out.println("Tu numero es menor");

        }

        sc.nextLine(); //LIMPIEZA DE BUFFER.

        System.out.print("Quieres volver a intentar? (s|n)->");
        respuesta= sc.nextLine();

        } while(respuesta.equals("s"));

}
}
```

Simplemente después de pedir los datos numéricos y vayas a pedir los de tipo `String`, justo antes del `String` introduces un `sc.nextLine();`

Si no controlas mucho Java aun, esto puede ser algo difícil de entender, te recomiendo que busques informacion sobre la **clase Scanner** y los **Buffer de memoria**.

Un saludo!

Comment: Ya lo arreglé, borré el 2do objeto y al leer la respuesta lo hice así respuesta=sc.next(); en vez de así respuesta=sc.nextLine();
Aún así no entiendo la lógica en ambos casos, ¿alguien me ayuda? Edición: Esto lo escribía mientras no había respuestas, pero ya entendí, gracias.

Comment: Estupendo, un placer! :)